# Excel: apply formula to each cell before SUM operation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a SUM on a range of cells but instead of using the value in the cell as IS I need to extract a piece from each cell to use in the sum. In the example below I need to use the value before the - sign.

```
   A
1  1-3
2  2-60
3  5-3
4  =SUM(A1:A3)
```

SUM should be the addition of the first piece (before the -) so 1 + 2 + 5

I found a way to extract the data by using

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("-",A1,1)-1) = 1
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("-",A2,1)-1) = 2
=LEFT(A3, SEARCH("-",A3,1)-1) = 5
```

But how can I SUM the value of these formulas without having to use any more additional cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array formula: `=SUM(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A3, SEARCH(A1:A3, "-")-1)))`. Then press Shift-Ctrl-Enter to tell Excel this is an array formula.

Comment: super!! thank you. is there a way to not have to remember to do shift + ctrl +  enter?

Comment: If you use `SUMPRODUCT` in place of `SUM` then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER is not required

Comment: I think you always have to do Shift-Ctrl-Enter when you first create the formula, to let Excel know it is an array formula. But when you edit it, copy or fill across, you may not need to.

Answer (score 1):

### sumproduct alternative

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(A1:A3,"-")-1)))
```

This is a none CSE formula that peforms array like operations.  As such you should avoid full column references within the sumproduct.  Also note, things may go a little "WONKY" if there is no - in the cell.  To avoid that you could add a - to the very end.  Formula would look something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A3&"-",FIND(A1:A3&"-","-")-1)))
```

That will work when you just have integers and no formula