# Excel: apply formula before summing

Tags: arrays, excel, sum

I want to sum over the binary values without having to insert the column of binaries (cf. figure below).

What I tried so far is the procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868189/excel-apply-formula-to-each-cell-before-sum-operation?rq=1), howerver, I couldn't figure out how to define the range with ":" properly in my case.

Best,
F.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in a cell and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=SUM(IF(A4:A8 + B4:B8 + C4:C8 = 7;1;0))
```

Comment: Does this worked for you or are you still facing some problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a nasty array formula using a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$4:$A$8+$B$4:$B$8+$C$4:$C$8=$B$1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I refer to another EXCEL file to retrieve the data for my calculations. Now, whenever I have the source document open, everything works fine. However, if I close the document containing the data, I get "#REF!". This happens although the file path adjusts to an absolute one.

I found some information stating that some functions in excel don't work with referenced files being closed. Are sumproduct and if such functions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. I NEVER refer to data in other workbooks. It is flaky at best and people have a tendency to rename or move workbooks, breaking the link. If I need data from another workbook, I write a macro which permanently copies the data.